# VeraCrypt volume does not decrypt - lost the password. Error message: "Source: MountVolume:8299"

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I created several encrypted file containers last year. I'm opening them up for the first time since and can't remember the exact password. I've tried many passwords that I typically use - over 10 of them - but no luck so far.

The error message I get is:

Operation failed due to one or more of the following:

- Incorrect password.
- Incorrect Volume PIM number.
- Incorrect PRF (hash).
- Not a valid volume.
  Source: MountVolume:8299

I am somewhat certain the password I used was one of these passwords on my list but not fully certain. I didn't use a PIM or PRF that I remember, just the standard password and moving the mouse around the screen.

I've done some searching & research on the subject of people having problems decrypting encrypted file containers they've created with VeraCrypt and it looks like this situation is fairly typical? I've tried doing the restore from embedded volume header but that requires a password, so I'm still faced with the same issue.

Maybe it has to do with the drive I choose to mount the file? The VeraCrypt screen shows these drives: A, B, G and onwards. I don't remember which drive I chose to mount them last year. I always choose one above E: so this probably isn't the issue but I figured I'd mention it just in case.

The fixes I've read include:

1. renaming the file
2. change the file location (I copied it to a USB stick)
3. run Veracrypt in Administrator mode

I have other VeraCrypt volumes that haven't given me any problems. I've even created new ones in the past week and they encrypt/decrypt fine. I've even copied them to another computer and opened them there.

Is the volume header possibly corrupted? How can I use the 'Restore volume header' function if it requires the password?

This is using VeraCrypt 1.23-Hotfix-2 on a Windows 7 computer.

EDIT: 
The main thing I'm trying to understand here is this: is there a bug or exception in how Veracrypt functions that could be causing this IF one of the passwords I tried is the correct one?

If others have been able to successfully open an encrypted file container after doing one or more of the fixes mentioned above where they had the correct password, meaning they used the same password in the failed tries, then maybe Veracrypt isn't stable or reliable enough to place valuable or important files in its encrypted file containers?

If there's such a thing as the volume header getting corrupted and one has to do a 'restore' to successfully open the file or to do funky stuff like renaming the file or closing/reopening Veracrypt, then I may have used the correct password and it didn't open the file.

Does a volume header getting corrupted prevent the decryption of a file container?

EDIT 2:
I think it would be clearer if I summarize my question to this:

Given that the error message gives 4 possible causes and I've eliminated 2 of them, is there a way to determine whether the cause is a corrupted volume header or an incorrect password? If it's not corrupted, I'll keep trying different passwords, otherwise it would be a waste of time as I can use the correct password and get the same error message.

Comment: Also note that you may have used TrueCrypt legacy compatibility mode to create the container or they may have changed the default settings (wrt PIM, PRF, ..) within the versions you use now and you used back then. Note that VeraCrypt explicitly does not store key derivation parameters visibly.

Comment: SEJPM - I've tried is checking the TC mode box and trying my list of passwords, though I'm pretty sure I used VC. I even opened TC and tried opening the file there. No luck with either.

Comment: Thank you to whoever migrated my question here to SuperUser.

Comment: I observed something strange though it might not be related. I created another encrypted file container in the same laptop then copied it to a USB drive and put it into a second laptop. When I opened it there, there were no files - the files I had inside the container were missing. I did a 'restore' of the embedded header as I had the password, and it ran fine including showing the screen with the setting of random data. I mounted it but it still didn't have any files. I re-copied the original file to the USB and tried again and this time it has the files.

Answer (score 2):

Not being a professional cryptographer you have no chance to decrypt your VeraCrypt encrypted volumes — if it would be possible, the VeraCrypt encryption would have no sense, have it?

Fixes that you read and tried are absurd in the context of my previous sentence.

Even a professional cryptographer would have no chance without other supporting information, if your forgotten password was strong enough.

> How can I use the 'Restore volume header' function if it requires the password?

Again, you have no chance without the correct password.

VeraCrypt is not a toy, it's a serious encryption tool, open source, without some obscure tricks you are able to reveal.

---

*Answers to appended text in your question:*

> If others have been able to successfully open ...

No, they not been able. There is no evidence. (There is a difference between claiming they did something  and really doing it.)

Follow me:

1. Did renaming a file change its contents?
2. Did copying the file to another location change its contents?
3. Did running VeraCrypt in Administrator mode change the file contents?

VeraCrypt encrypts / decrypts only an encrypted file container *contents*, irrespective of its name, location, or user privileges. User privileges may only *allow / forbid* the read / write access to a file, without changing the way how VeraCrypt will process it.

> ... then maybe Veracrypt isn't stable or reliable enough to place valuable or important files in its encrypted file containers?

VeraCrypt didn't care about value or importance of your files, it simply encrypts whatever you want.

In some very rare occasions an encrypted file container *may be damaged,* of course, but then renaming / copying / using Administrator rights will now repair it.

> If there's such a thing as the volume header getting corrupted and one has to do a 'restore' to successfully open the file ...

The volume header is *crucial* for decrypting / encrypting the encrypted volume file, so VeraCrypt stores its copy in another place of the encrypted volume file. "Restoring it" means simply copy it back to header. But because this copy is encrypted, too, you need a correct password to perform this operation.

> Does a volume header getting corrupted prevent the decryption of a file container?

Yes, it will prevent, as I already meant. But you may restore it from the (hopefully uncorrupted) copy of it — if you know the correct password.

Comment: MarianD - thanks for the reply. I edited my question to be clearer.

Comment: Is there a way to determine whether the cause is a corrupted volume header or an incorrect password? If it's not corrupted, I'll keep trying different passwords, otherwise it would be a waste of time as I can use the correct password and get the same error message.

Comment: *“Is there a way to determine whether the cause is a corrupted volume header or an incorrect password? “* — **No,** of course. The main goal in cryptography is “make the life of possible attacker as difficult as it is possible” which mean "no info".  — Please consider voting my answer up and / or accepting it if it was useful for you (click on upper triangle and check mark at top of it).

Comment: Actually, privileges may prevent VeraCrypt from providing you access to the virtual file system of the container as a new volume.

Comment: @SEJPM, isn't it stated in my answer?

Comment: @MarianD my reading of that point was that it privileges may mostly prevent the application from reading / modifying the container file, not so much that it may not be able to hook into the driver stack and present a new volume (which is why I clarified).

Comment: SEJPM - thanks for the reply. How do I check the privileges? Is this addressed by running in admin mode?

Comment: @theman normally VeraCrypt should complain early and with a different error if privileges are missing as it can clearly trace that back / notice it.

Comment: Can anything be gleaned from the "Source: MountVolume:8299" in the error message? I wish VC would be specific with describing the error instead of listing 4 possible causes of the error.

Comment: Please, first appreciate my answer by upvoting / accepting it.

Comment: MarianD - upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you create the container with Truecrypt instead of Veracrypt? Then you have to check "TrueCrypt mode".